# Sort jquery mobile listview based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working with jquery Mobile 1.0, I need to show an order list. It will show all record by default and filter record on dropdown selection.

This is what I've tried

```jsl
function show_List(urlObj, options) {
    var sortValue = 0;
    var headerTextList;
    $("#dList").bind("change", function (event, ui) {
        sortValue = $(this).val();
        if (sortValue == 1) {
            headerTextList = "<B><font color=navy>Completed Work Orders </font></B>";
        }
        else if (sortValue == 2) {
            headerTextList = "<B><font color=navy>In Process Work Orders </font></B>";
        }
        else if (sortValue == 3) {
            headerTextList = "<B><font color=navy>Pending Work Orders </font></B>";
        }
        else if (sortValue == 0) {
            headerTextList = "<B><font color=navy>All Work Orders </font></B>";
        }

        getListView(sortValue, urlObj, options, headerTextList);
       // ajax call based on sortvalue

    });
    getListView(sortValue, urlObj, options, headerTextList);// ajax call
    // ajax call based on sortvalue
}
```

Above method call on

```html
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {

    var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
    var qrcode = /^#Orderlist/;
    if (u.hash.search(qrcode) !== -1) {
        show_List(u, data.options);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  )};
```

Its working fine but it call the method `getListView` twice and I want only one ajax call, any idea?

Comment: add `cache:false` in your ajax call, maybe it's the cache issue with IE if you use IE.
Could you add some console.log and see what doesn't trigger?

Comment: @TecHunter problem is getListView triggering twice

Comment: ah sorry, well try the commonly used e.stopPropagation() in your change. also prefer using `.on` instead of `.bind` or `.live`